# Submit PayPal form using JS not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit

I have a PayPal form as follows: (some fields are added using jQuery)

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
    <input type="hidden" value="_s-xclick" name="cmd">
    <input type="hidden" value="sdfgsdfg" name="hosted_button_id">
    <input type="button" value="Purchase One Year License" name="submit" class="pp_button" id="35" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
    <input type="hidden" value="35" name="cs_project_id">                                            
    <input type="hidden" value="6d04c7a241ad4415eb194a90dc252b09" name="cs_transaction_id">
</form>
```

I'm trying to submit the form using the 3rd `input` element (`type="button"`) using this code:

```
$(".pp_button").click(function()
{
    var button = $(this);
    button.parent().submit();
});
```

This should work fine right? I'm using `var button` because of other parts later in the `click()` function. I've checked the `tagName` of `button.parent()` and it's given as `FORM`, so that's fine...

What have I done wrong here? This usually works fine... Is it because I'm inserting tags (the last two `input` tags) from an AJAX call? Something else? A lack of mature cheddar on my desk?

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just set the input type from `button` to `submit`? This would make the button submit the form and not need any Javascript?

Or if you want to use javascript (jQuery), you could give the form an ID like this:

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" id="paypal_form">
```

And when you want to submit the form you can call:

```
$("#paypal_form").submit();
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a form control named `submit`. This clobbers the `submit` function with an `HTMLElementNode`.

The best solution is probably to not use JavaScript here. You say that you need other things to happen, but the user might have JS turned off, so if they are important you would almost certainly be better off finding a different way.

The simple solution is to change the name.

The complicated solution would be to get a copy of the submit method from another form, then use it with the form you want to submit:

```
 document.createElement('form').submit.apply(this.form);
```

Comment: Annoyingly I can't change the name (at least I think); it might be used by PayPal in some way... I'll test it out with another name.